# T-SQL 2008- Get the highest path

Tags: t-sql, substring, string-length

I have a table with a field called PATH; this field has the following format (each record is a new row):

```
PartitionA \ PathA
PartitionA \ PathA \ Location
PartitionA \ PathA \ Location \ Share
PartitionA \ PathA \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserA
PartitionA \ PathA \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserA \ fileA.txt
PartitionA \ PathB
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location \ Share
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserB
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserB \ fileB.txt
```

...

I want to get the highest folder for each user. For this example, i want to get:

```
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserA
PartitionA \ PathB \ Location \ Share \ FolderUserB
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying you should or shouldn't restructure the data, but this would be easier to solve if the data was hierarchical - either using normalization or the hierarchical data type. However... would it be sneaky to just:

```
order by len(path) - len(replace(path,' \ ','') desc
```

(along with whatever grouping etc you need)